# One DropDownList does not fire SelectedIndexChanged But Other Does

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am having a issue that I just can figure why it is happening

the situation is that I have two dropdownlists, both set up the same way

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DocumentLink" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DocumentLink_Changed">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="PageLink" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageLink_Changed">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Their events look like this

```
protected void DocumentLink_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList DocumentLink = sender as DropDownList;
        LinkParam = DocumentLink.SelectedValue.ToString();
        DescriptionParam = DocumentLink.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
    protected void PageLink_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList PageLink = sender as DropDownList;
        LinkParam = PageLink.SelectedValue.ToString();
        DescriptionParam = PageLink.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

In the case of the DropDown called "PageLink" the event handler fires. However for the "DocumentLink" the event handler does not. In debug I see that page load is fired but the event drops off after the page load and never enters DocumentLink_Changed

As an point of interest if I use a telerik radComboBox in place of the DropDownList using the same set-up it does work.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="DocumentLink" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DocumentLink_Changed">
                </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

with the event handler like this

```
protected void DocumentLink_Changed(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
```

unfortunately I need to use Dropdownlists for my project.

What could be causing this?

UPDATE

I have taken the working dropdownlist and used the LINQ binding for the dropdownlist that did not work. The result was that the PageLink dropdownlist began to behave just like the 'DocumentLink' dropdownlist. This makes me believe that the issue might be in the binding method but they the two are very similar and I do see results in the dropdownlist

this is my binding

```
if (selectedValue == 3)
            {
                DropDownList select = lvLinks.InsertItem.FindControl("PageLink") as DropDownList;
                List<IPW_Links_get_document_listResult> getList = (from i in lqContext.IPW_Links_get_document_list(0, "my stuff") select i).ToList();
                select.DataSource = getList;
                select.DataTextField = "DocumentName";
                select.DataValueField = "FolderPath";
                select.DataBind();

            }
            if (selectedValue == 2)
            {
                DropDownList select = lvLinks.InsertItem.FindControl("PageLink") as DropDownList;
                List<IPW_Links_get_available_pagesResult> getList = (from i in lqContext.IPW_Links_get_available_pages(PortalId) select i).ToList();
                select.DataSource = getList;
                select.DataTextField = "TabName";
                select.DataValueField = "TabPath";
                select.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

do check if you have any statements in the PageLoad event that alters the dropdownlists. If you have a databinding statement or a selection reset statement in the page load event , then make sure it is under the *if not ispostback* conditional snippet.

Comment: thanks for the help but this doesn't seem to be the case since one both drop down lists execute the same workflow, one work and the other doesn't

Comment: @MarkHollas from the code you have posted, it seems like you are binding the "PageLink" dropdown with two sets of data based on a variable "SelectedValue". Is it possible for you to paste the entire code for page load. I would also suggest to enable trace and do a  few trace.write() statements to check which all lines has been executed. you can view the same by visiting apppath/trace.axd

Comment: Also check if you have duplicate values in the bound data.